# When someone is available = When someone is free?

Tags: general-vs-specific

I left a voice mail saying "Can I speak to Cindy when she is available?". Does it sound weird at all? It was to an office.

Comment: It's not weird at all...

Comment: Someone being 'free' could present precisely the same problem, think over. Neither is better or worse. It only depends on how one looks at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like Cindy to return your call, why not explicitly request that? If you didn't leave your number or other contact information, that would be pretty weird.

There's nothing wrong with your use of "when she is available", it just doesn't seem to fit the circumstances.

Comment: Sounds perfectly alright to me.